# Уведомление в вопросе и ответе

Tags: поддержка

В комментариях есть синтаксис, позволяющий обратиться к конкретному пользователю, при этом он получает уведомление: @user1111. Как такое же сделать в вопросе или ответе?

Если такая функция уже есть, то её необходимо внести в [справку по markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: `В комментариях есть синтаксис, позволяющий обратиться к конкретному пользователю, при этом он получает уведомление` - с помарочкой: если он принимал уже участие в обсуждении под вопросом/ответом... или же если это и есть автор вопроса/ответа и в комментариях общаются более 2-ух человек, включая автора.........Обратиться к произвольному участнику сообщества так нельзя. А к тем, кто уже принимал участие - всегда пожалуйста, но только в комментариях

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ещё можно упоминать авторов правок.

Answer (score 4):

Уведомления через упоминание ника в теле сообщений не предусмотрены. Более того, даже упоминания в комментариях не действуют на любого участника. То есть он должен до этого как-то поучаствовать в дискуссии: оставить комментарий или внести правку в сообщение. Иначе упоминание ника не приведет к уведомлению.